# How to associate contacts to opportunities?

Tags: opportunity, opportunitycontactrole, opportunity-teams

I need to associate Contacts to Opportunities.

One way will be to delete/hide the "New" button, and only leave it on the contact page: That's not acceptable by sales/marketing team.

So, what's my other options?

There can be many contacts related to any given oppty.

Is contact roles the solution? How can I make it a mandatory upon oppty creation?

Comment: Do you happen to have Dan Appleman's Advanced Apex Programming second edition?  He covers this exact example in chapter 4.  It's an excellent resource for any developer IMO.

Comment: Nice spot @sfdc_ninja, check out "An Interesting Challenge" on p62 of the second edition Saariko

Comment: Dont have it. I mostly count on free reads and articles on the web. I feel books are obsolete. But thats debate for another occasion.

Comment: Not a fan of "I feel books are obsolete," as they are a way for you to help yourself instead of needing to post a question to a community. Perhaps you are making a joke, but when someone tells you to look up the answer in a book, please say "thank you" and go do it instead of rejecting that method.

Answer (score 3):

Contact Roles is indeed the prescribed solution.

You cannot make it mandatory upon opportunity creation, unless you create a Visualforce page for creating new opportunities.

You could block the opportunity from moving to a next stage unless Contacts ar linked to the Opportunity. For this you'd need a trigger on Contact Roles that updates a field on Opportunity. See an example here:

http://www.oyecode.com/2012/01/salesforce-trigger-to-count-contact.html